# How to navigate from Native Controller to React-Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I am developing an app using Native & React-Native. I can easily Navigate from RN to Native via Bridge. But I stuck in navigating from Native to RN. I don't want to simply pop, I need to open a new Controller of RN.
For navigation in RN, I am using **react-native-router-flux**